# How many items should a list optimally display?

Tags: lists, pagination, search-results

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is 10 search results per page the best?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16935/is-10-search-results-per-page-the-best)

We have a webshop where the products are listed in rows of 3, each being 340 pixels high. One of our categories now has 38 products and we're thinking it's time to implement some pagination.

Are there any best practices, recommendations or considerations as to how many products each page should display by default?

Comment: What kind of display are you using? Are we talking about eg. book covers being shown in a grid, or a list of links like on Google?

Comment: It's square with a large product image and a name + price below. I'm not sure if that's what you want to know, so you can see the listing here: http://smykketilbud.dk/halskaeder-vedhaeng (it's a work in progress)

Comment: This question was posted before the one cited in possible duplicates.

Comment: @dnbrv - the other question is much more complete of a question. It has a great deal more detail put into it. That's probably why this one was closed.

Answer (score -1):

Certainly time to introduce some pagination.  It has been well documented that customers tend to freeze when offered too much choice and run from the store.  Try to ask the customers to narrow their search then yoiu can off them a subset